# Electron-Packager spawn ENOTDIR

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-packager

I am working on a electron app, i use electron with react and threejs, now i can not build a windows application anymore. Building an Linux version or a Mac version works fine.

*My npm commande is:*

```
$ electron-packager ./build ProjectName --platform=win32 --arch=all --overwrite --packageManager=yarn --prune=true --out=out/windows --asar --icon=icon/icon.png.ico
```

Now i get following not saying error message.

```
spawn ENOTDIR
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Does `out/windows` exist beneath your working directory?

Comment: Yes nothing changed, I think it is a system bug which came with an update from wine.